# I want to use Google Chrome Search field, NOT the address bar

Tags: google-chrome

I installed Google Chrome on MacBook Pro. But when I try to type something in the "Search" field but instead my text goes up into the address bar.

I find it difficult to do searches in the address bar. I like to type keywords in a "Search" field in the center, like I did with regular Google, Yahoo, Aol and other browsers.

Is there a way to adjust this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you in google.com or the New Tab page? In the New Tab page, it will always default to typing in the omni-bar (and there is no way you can change that), however in google.com, it will type in the search box instead of the omni-bar. Currently, you cannot change the page that comes up when opening a new tab natively, but you can download extensions that will do this for you. [Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) is an extension that does that, with that extension you can set the redirect page to "https://www.google.com".